# Adding a self-mutating object to redux store

Tags: javascript, redux

I have a class in a javascript file which should create objects to a redux store. Obviously, the class has functions which mutate the properties within itself.

Example, I have a class:

```
export default class Test {
  constructor(val) {
    this.val = val;
  }

  changeProp() {
    this.val = 3;
  }
}
```

then in reducer

```
case actionTypes.SET_TEST:
  return {
    ...state,
    obj: new Test(10);
  };
```

As you see, changeProp() changes the properties from within, but is this bad practice? Do I need to mutate these properties through the reducers immutably?

Comment: Yes, it's generally bad practice. The Redux store should be immutable. See [Redux FAQ: Immutable Data](https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data)

Comment: imho, it's a lot more important to only edit state via reducers than it is to use strict immutability on a low level.

Comment: Hmm, I wanted the object to be accessible globally... But adding reducers for all the properties in that object now seems overkill. Is Context a good alternative for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: _It is highly recommended that you only put **plain serializable** objects, arrays, and primitives into your store._ ([ref.](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/docs/faq/OrganizingState.md#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state))

Comment: I see, that's too bad. Thank you

Comment: BTW, depending on how complex your state object is, you don't have to have a reducer for every property. Your action could be something like `{ type: SET_TEST, payload: { val: 3 } }`, and inside your reducer, something like `{ ...state, obj: { ...state.obj, action.payload } }`